# Pine script tag problem, how can I prevent the code I write from putting tags under each candle?

Tags: pine-script

how can i prevent my code from putting tags under each candle. Thanks.

```
//@version=5
indicator('$ Control ema ver.', overlay=true)

len50 = input.int(5, minval=1, title='EMA')
src50 = input(close, title='Source')
out50 = ta.ema(src50, len50)

all = close >= out50 
satt = close <= out50 

plotshape(all, title='Buy', text='¡', location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, 
size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))  

plotshape(satt, title='Sel', text='!', location=location.abovebar, style=shape.labeldown, 
size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick you can do is check if your condition was not true the previous bar and is true the current bar. This way you would know that your signal's state has changed.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Control ema ver', overlay=true)

len50 = input.int(5, minval=1, title='EMA')
src50 = input(close, title='Source')
out50 = ta.ema(src50, len50)

all = close >= out50
satt = close <= out50

buy = not all[1] and all
sell = not satt[1] and satt

plotshape(buy, title='Buy', text='¡', location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))  
plotshape(sell, title='Sel', text='!', location=location.abovebar, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```